# Como organizar melhor o foreach

Tags: php

Tenho esse `foreach` que está funcionando perfeitamente, mas acho ele um código muito poluído, muito grande. Há alguma forma de reescrever esse `foreach` de uma forma mais correta? Tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas estou otimizando o código de uma forma geral.

```php
<?php

$dados = array(
   '<tr><td>ID: 120</td></tr>',
   '<tr><td>Classe de aferimento: Natural</td></tr>',
   '<tr><td>Área de atuação: Airsoft</td></tr>',
   '<tr><td>Valor de custo: R$ 1.220,50</td></tr>',
   '<tr><td>Local: Santa-Fé</td></tr>'
);

foreach ($dados as $value) {
    $valor = strip_tags(trim($value));
    $xpl = explode(":",$valor);

    $pos = strpos($xpl[0], "ID");
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
        $cltId = trim($xpl[1]);
    }

    $pos = strpos($xpl[0], "Classe");
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
        $cltClasse = trim($xpl[1]);
    }

    $pos = strpos($xpl[0], "Área");
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
        $cltArea = trim($xpl[1]);
    }

    $pos = strpos($xpl[0], "Valor");
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
        $cltValor = trim($xpl[1]);
        $cltValor = explode(" ", $cltValor);
        $cltValor = number_format($cltValor[1], 2, '.', '');
    }

    $pos = strpos($xpl[0], "Local");
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
      $cltLocal = trim($xpl[1]);
    }

}
echo "Dados a serem iseridos no Banco de Dados";
echo "<br />";
echo "ID do solicitante: ".$cltId;
echo "<br />";
echo "Classe do solicitante: ".$cltClasse;
echo "<br />";
echo "Área do solicitante: ".$cltArea;
echo "<br />";
echo "Valor cobrado: ".$cltValor;
echo "<br />";
echo "Local de ação: ".$cltLocal;
?>
```

Comment: O que o código faz? Qual é a entrada e qual é a saída produzida?

Comment: A entrada é aquela do array $dados e a saída é individual cada um com uma variável diferente que são as variáveis que começam com $clt...

Comment: A variable `$i` é inútil. Porque você está usando ela?

Comment: Realmente @MauryDeveloper vou editar para excluir.

Comment: De onde vem esse *array*? Ele será sempre nesse mesmo formato?

Comment: Será sempre nesse mesmo formato @AndersonCarlosWoss . Fiz um crawler de um site onde já existe essa tabela. Separei apenas as <tr>.

Comment: `$pos = strpos($xpl[0], "ID");
    if ($pos === false) {
    } else {
        $cltId = trim($xpl[1]);
    }` Uma sugestão para minimizar esse código: `$pos = strpos($xpl[0], "ID");
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $cltId = trim($xpl[1]);
    }` É inútil usar comparação se não executar nada.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Boa! Já deu uma diminuida!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todas as linhas da sua tabela possuem o mesmo padrão: `<nome>: <valor>`. Então você consegue tirar proveito deste padrão para simplificar seu código:

```php
$resultado = [];

foreach ($dados as $dado) {
  list($nome, $valor) = explode(':', strip_tags($dado));
  $resultado[trim($nome)] = trim($valor);
}
```

Basicamente você percorre os valores do seu *array*, remove as tags HTML, divide no caractere dois pontos, `:`, e define o primeiro valor como nome da coluna e o segundo como valor da mesma, salvando em `$resultado`.

Ao final terá um *array* associativo:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 120
    [Classe de aferimento] => Natural
    [Área de atuação] => Airsoft
    [Valor de custo] => R$ 1.220,50
    [Local] => Santa-Fé
)
```

Podendo fazer:

```php
echo <<<RESULTADO
Dados a serem iseridos no Banco de Dados
ID do solicitante: {$resultado["ID"]}
Classe do solicitante: {$resultado["Classe de aferimento"]}
Área do solicitante: {$resultado["Área de atuação"]}
Valor cobrado: {$resultado["Valor de custo"]}
Local de ação: {$resultado["Local"]}
RESULTADO;
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AliveLastLoops)</sup>

Comment: Deu melhorada 300%. Ficou legivelmente para visualizar e economizar linhas.

Answer (score 0):

```
$titles = array('ID', 'Classe', 'Área', 'Valor', 'Local');
$resultado = array();

foreach ($dados as $value) {
    $valor = strip_tags(trim($value));
    $xpl = explode(":", $valor);

    if (in_array($xpl[0], $titles)) {

        $resultado[$xpl[0]] = trim($xpl[1]);

        if ($xpl[0] === 'Valor') {
            $cltValor = explode(" ", $resultado[$xpl[0]]);
            $resultado[$xpl[0]] = number_format($cltValor[1], 2, '.', '');
        }

    }
}
```

Para exibir os valores:

```
echo "Dados a serem inseridos no Banco de Dados";
echo "<br />";
echo "ID do solicitante: " . $resultado['ID'];
echo "<br />";
echo "Classe do solicitante: " . $resultado['Classe'];
echo "<br />";
echo "Área do solicitante: " . $resultado['Área'];
echo "<br />";
echo "Valor cobrado: " . $resultado['Valor'];
echo "<br />";
echo "Local de ação: " . $resultado['Local'];
```

Comment: É exatamente isso! Entretanto, o in_array só funciona se os valores forem exatos. O exemplo acima só funciona com o ID e com o Local. Mas já deu uma luz e tanto. Vou tentar aliar o in_array com o strpos. Sabe alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Os seus valores não são exatos?

Comment: Não. E explode retorna "Classe do solicitante", por exemplo. Então o in_array retorna false in_array($xpl[0], "Classe").

Answer (score -5):

Tem sim, na view dessa lista pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Sexos</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($dados as $dado) :?>
   <tr>
       <td><?=$dado->id?></td>
       <td><?=$dado->nome?></td>
       <td><?=$dado->sexo?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Dessa forma fica mais otimizado o código o PHP mesmo tem esse jeito de comportamento para front-end, espero ter ajudado.

Pegando dados de uma tabela com JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var tbody = $('tbody > tr > td');

   $.each(tbody, function(index, item){
       var item = $(item).text();
       var dados = item.replace(",", ".");
       console.log(dados);
       debugger;
   })
})
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96609/discussion-on-answer-by-lucas-antonio-como-organizar-melhor-o-foreach) e pode prosseguir lá se houver interesse